# running a binary in SLURM

Tags: bash, slurm

I was trying to run a binary, `"rafb"` in `SLURM` using `"--wrap"`, like
    `sbatch --wrap rafb`

but it is showing
`sbatch: error: Script arguments are not permitted with the --wrap option.`

Without this `"--wrap"`, it was showing

```
sbatch: error: This does not look like a batch script.  The first
sbatch: error: line must start with #! followed by the path to an interpreter.
sbatch: error: For instance: #!/bin/sh
```

Is there any other way to avoid writing `"#!/bin/bash"` in the script?

Comment: is this the entire command line: `sbatch --wrap rafb` ? The error message suggests otherwise.

Comment: yes, where  "rafb" is the name of the binary

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me if I write it like this:

```
sbatch --wrap="rafb"
```

I know this question is rather old, but since there has been no solution yet and I just faced the same problem, I would like to share my solution with others facing the same problem.